# How to discipline overeager engineer

Tags: united-states, promotion, canada, discipline

I have a software engineer on my staff that has been very useful. He basically trains himself on new technologies on a weekly basis, and can memorize and apply the latest O'Reilly textbook over a weekend, and master the content within a month. He's been on board with our company (5000+ as of January) for a little over 4 years, and has done well with us (i.e. stocks, bonuses), puts in at least 15 hours overtime per week, etc.; and has received a promotion from intermediate engineer to senior engineer in his first year (mostly due to his hiring manager messing up and hiring him "too low").

He's had a lot of success these past 3 years, and is pushing (excessively) for a promotion to "engineering director", which is the next level up (2 levels beneath me). In his words, he's got the knowledge, drive, and mindset to make it to this level, and plans to "be a director before he's 33". While I wish that for him, the company doesn't promote people unless they've worked in a role for a least 3 years and can prove they're ready for the next level.

He's recently completed his annual review, and while he got a raise and encouragement that he's close to reaching the next level/promotion, he wasn't happy. He insisted on knowing every detail of how he's not yet ready for the next promotion, and insisted on having checkins each month to know if/when he's ready so he can be promoted early rather than having to wait another year "needlessly" to be promoted during annual reviews. I tried to encourage him to be patient, but he's insistent that "time spent in the current chair shouldn't be a factor", while management insists that it's important to "de-risk" a candidate.

**We've had a serious problem with him this month:** since a formal meeting where he's noted he's not happy being magically promoted on a whim, he's made a point of cutting overtime to nothing, focusing on his personal blog/LinkedIn to show off his knowledge, focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) and **encouraging other engineers to do the same**. This has caused a lot of disruptions in the company, and I'm receiving recommendations to encourage this employee to quit. How do I straighten out this formerly useful employee? He has accrued 2 years of severance in lieu of overtime (due to unique circumstances), and senior management (on principal) doesn't want to pay $700,000 to "fire" someone.

Comment: "_the company doesn't promote people unless they've worked in a role for a least 3 years_" & "_... has received a promotion... in his first year_" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but just **how much** are you paying him that his overtime has added up to 700k over 4 years? 700k is about double of what I make in 4 years at my full-time software engineering job (but I don't get paid for overtime either).

Comment: Ok, I've edited this for the last time, I can lock it permanently if someone edits it again, but given I doubt I'll have the rights to unlock it soon, maybe we can just agree to leave it as it is this time, okay? :)

Comment: What country is this actually taking place in? Two country tags make things rather confusing.

Comment: Overtime is _over_time. That means it's NOT mandatory. Why do you think it's mandatory?

Comment: Getting promoted because you work really hard in your spare time doesn't really count as "being magically promoted on a whim" to me

Comment: The question I see here is: "How does this useful employee straighten out this currently useless leader?" Instead of throttling their ambition and activity, perhaps you might be better served advocating for them. Set non-technical goals for this person and establish a growth plan to serve them. Connect that plan to a vision that leads to a director position. I have the exact opposite problem. I have engineers who think "number of years" gets them to senior.

Comment: "senior management (on principal) doesn't want to pay $700,000 to "fire" someone." This doesn't make sense. Does the employee forfeit their overtime if they quit? And if 2 years severance = 700k, does that mean they're making $30k/year? Does he generate $350k/year in value? Is the director position a management position?

Comment: Fire him, have him contact my company.  Ask him if he has any siblings that are looking for work, and tell them to contact my company, too.

Answer (score 747):

> he's made a point of cutting OT to nothing, focusing on his personal blog/LinkedIn to show off his knowledge, focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) and encouraging other engineers to do the same.

So let me sum this up: you told your employee that the time he invests and the skills he brings **do not** advance him. The only thing to advance him in your company is more time of his rear end spent in a company's chair. Because *that* is what counts.

And you are *surprised*, that he promptly decided to focus on plain time spent in his chair, instead of his skills and time he invests?

It's exactly what you told him: "Do not expect to be promoted just for the hard work you do or the knowledge you have". Why would he do those things, that I guess are on his own dime and time? You have your rules. They have theirs.

If you *expect* overtime and learning in their free time, you should have written that into their working contract the last times you promoted them.

Doing (only) what is in your contract hardly constitutes a legal reason to fire someone (assuming you are in a country with labor laws where you need a reason).

Encouraging others to do what is in *their* contracts might not be what your company likes, but I have a feeling that it will also not be against the duties of an employee in your country.

The question you have to ask is: if they came from the outside, would you consider them for a director position? If so, your company policies basically *force* them to go look for opportunities outside, because you won't "hire" them based on where they come from. Maybe it's time for that to change. Maybe not. But you probably will lose this person to another company sooner or later. If you would *not* consider them for a director position if they applied from the outside, then you need to tell them why so they can improve. And it's probably something else than "3 years in the chair".

Right now you are between a rock and a hard place. Neither of you can give in and expect the other side to not remember that in future negotiations.

Maybe the easiest way is to have a talk with them and tell them that you would give them a glowing recommendation for a director job at another company, if they start working their "normal" OT schedule again. That should solve your 700K problem as far as I understood you. If they *cannot* find a director job outside your company with their current skillset, maybe they'll be more humble and find a compromise to stay at yours.

Comment: This guy is a precious gem. Too bad your company can't afford him.

Comment: On top of this answer, I assume he is aware of his severance package....and all the rules he has to follow to get it. Make sure to inform him of that. Hopefully management will fire him for doing his exact job as described by his contract, lose 700k, lose him, and lose other employees once they realize all the extra work they do is pointless, and that their employment terms are not *actually* what both sides agree to, and the company is taking above and beyond advantage of the concept of, „work hard, advance“

Comment: Not sure how I feel about the `getting him back to "normal" OT schedule` idea :|

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri  Exactly. This situation is exactly how I fantasize a company would react if you really truly made yourself valuable. His decision to reduce overtime to zero is exactly the right decision because this company is literally threatened because this is the one person who is super loyal, knows what he's worth, and wants to be acknowledged and rewarded for it.  The company is afraid of having someone who actually is as smart as the person they envision.

Comment: True, you do not `discipline overeager engineer`, you motivate him! Especially that he is also highly competent, besides being overeager.

Comment: The "normal OT schedule" is a bit much to expect, but I think you could reasonably ask him to stop undermining the company by encouraging other employees to reduce their work.

Comment: "tell them that you would give them a glowing recommendation for a director job at another company, if they start working their "normal" OT schedule again." You seem to be suggesting that OP threatens to give an unfair recommendation if the employee decides to work only the contracted amount of hours

Comment: @Blueriver No, just a truthful one. And I think all parties agree that extra-work and commitment is the way to director, something the person in question currently is no longer showing. Do you think they will get a director job with a recommendation like "worked contracted hours to our satisfaction"? There is a world of difference between saying "This guy is great, but sadly our stupid company policy does not allow him to become director. A real asset, you will be happy you got him". And just plain "Yes, this person worked here from February 2016 to today."

Comment: The problem with this answer is that does not seem to comprehend that becoming more experienced is about more than just memorizing facts and applying them.  It's about **experiencing new things** (like, for example, weird bugs and how stupid and unreasonable end users can be).  If he keeps working this hard, **he'll be at the top of the list** when it comes time for promotions.  "Old age and (experience) will always beat youth and exuberance."

Comment: The way the OP words this Q makes it so there is no correct answer. Any answers are solely opinion. It sounds like the engineer needs to improve his soft skills. He upset you in some way with his over eagerness towards promotion. I think he is not experienced enough to win over management with his office politics. Maybe over his career he will figure out how book-learning is not how you advance in corporate. Usually companies only promote from within if someone is a leader and great at persuading their peers within their corporate culture. Usually I've seen companies hire  external candidates.

Comment: @RonJohn Oh it indeed is. But experience can be actively gained. Maybe the person needs better management skills? Or people skills? Maybe there is training available. Or maybe they can lead their own little pet project to prove themselves. Or they can lead the department while the director is away for their 3 months vacation. So many options to gain experience. But to be told to passively sit in a chair until experience hits them in the face is just insulting.

Comment: @nvoigt mentoring and management training are definitely a thing.  I don't think I've ever seen it in the tech sector, though.

Comment: This +100. The problem is not with the Engineer in question, but with the OP; their company and their narrow-minded mindset. What the OP describes is exactly how to 'stamp out' impertinent enthusiasm and motivation in their team.

Comment: If the employee is actively disrupting the output of other employees, presumably out of spite, then he is a childish gem, certainly not something I'd want in a director. A couple of years with your butt in a chair sorts that kind of thing out pretty well.

Answer (score 221):

*Do not* discipline him. He'll walk, and the company will have lost a very valuable asset.

It seems to me the right answer here is for you to sit down with whoever you need to sit down with to get the rules bent in this case and to make it happen. You've got what sounds like a brilliant engineer, and you're trying to force them out of the company.

The real kicker for me here is the unique severance package: somebody was presumably prepared to bend the rules there, so we know it *can* be done if the company wants to bend the rules. But now you're saying the company isn't prepared to bend the rules in a different way, and when your engineer does his own version of sticking to the rules, you try and make it a disciplinary offense?

The other thing to remember is that there is a non-zero chance this guy will be pretty influential in your industry/geography in a few years. What do you want him to think of you and your company?

Comment: This employee of his does not sound over eager. Instead, he sounds qualified for a director position. Companies should be able to bend the rules for those who are worth bending the rules for. Under no circumstances should anyone with talent & skill ever be disciplined. In fact, the company should be disciplined for not recognizing the talent.

Comment: That particular rule should be bent with every promotion.  Can you imagine if the military acted that way? Sorry Ike, we can't promote you to SACEUR, we'll just delay D-Day until 1946 while you get the seat time.  Stalin won't mind.

Comment: "Under **no** circumstances should anyone with talent & skill ever be disciplined." (emphasis mine) Actually I think that's taking it a bit far...

Comment: @MarkEntingh What part sounds qualified for a director position? That's what I'm missing. Senior engineer != director. Senior engineer doesn't even equal *lead or manager*. From the OP all we know is that the engineer is talented at engineering and likes to study. The engineer could completely lack the social skills needed for management or being a director. If I recall correctly, Google specifically made a non-managerial engineer career path, presumably for this exact reason. Engineering director will be a totally different skill set than the normal engineer employs

Comment: An alternative to bending the rules might be changing the rules, revising if the time criteria is still useful at all, if 3 years isn't too much and if it has to be strict, or rather a guidance. It should prevent other cases of such issue, and would no longer be something done just for the person in question but available - for those who deserve it (no inflation of promotions). It could perhaps be a good motivation compared to the knowledge that the following 3 years I won't be promoted no matter how I perform

Comment: @Mars I completely agree! I have seen many people get promoted way too fast to team lead (and that is so far from director) and they cannot manage anyone. Just because someone is a good engineer it doesn't mean they will be a good director, at all.

Comment: @MarkEntingh: "Under no circumstances should anyone with talent & skill ever be disciplined." Gotta agree with Michael here ... just think Jeffrey Epstein, Matt Lauer, Les Moonves, and on and on.

Comment: He use to asset, but no longer. Here is my reasoning. I think employees fall into 1 of 4 groups, adders, subtractors, multipliers, or dividers. If you are an adder, you add a few units of productivity, and a subtractor takes away a few units. A multiplier makes everyone more productive, while a divider makes everyone less productive. So, overtime and investigate technology is an adder. Making it easier for everyone to add more code faster is a multiplier. Now he had a mood change, and is encouraging everyone to slack off makes him a divider now. You need to fire dividers ASAP!

Comment: For all intents and purposes I think the company already *has* lost a very valuable asset by showing them exactly how little you valued them.

Comment: @NathanMelanson So after first poisoning his motivation and productivity you then recommend firing him for being unmotivated? I mean, sure, that's what passes for logic among managers and sociopaths I guess, but that's only going to communicate to everyone else in the workplace that they, too, should look for opportunities elsewhere because *this company does not value people*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the military does work that way (along with throwing out officers who fail to promote within a given time), and Eisenhower did have years of relevant time already when WWII kicked off. You're not wrong; that was just a terrible example.

Answer (score 168):

Referencing an answer I put in another question: [Does having two jobs simultaneously count for twice the experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145589/does-having-two-jobs-simultaneously-count-for-twice-the-experience/145603#145603)

Your company assumes that you count each day as fully worked. You state that your employee put 15 hours a week of overtime. In four years, that's around 18 months of extra time. That could be counted toward his experience if your company valued such employees.

You punished him by stating that you ignored that year and a half. You state that the company doesn't care about real input in work about what is written on the contract paper.

**You already straightened them out.** You had an employee who bent (or broke) company rules to provide better results. Then the company forced him to follow the rules to the letter.

Your company's mistake was typical to any corporation. Take everything give nothing back. And sometimes that bites back.

Comment: "Classic malicious compliance." OP's company told him that his OT didn't count, so now he's not doing OT. I wonder who's fault that is...

Comment: Mixed feelings here.  Agreed that the company’s approach is not good, and that the employee’s response is understandable.  But it also sounds like he has taken that response to an extremely childish level.  And such childishness is not a good thing in a “director” position.

Comment: @WGroleau No. He just went to corporation level. It's them who call him "millenial" and want to fire him because he stopped putting overtime and expressed his disappointment. He started playing by the rules that his company have written.

Comment: @WGroleau He put in an effort of 200%, went way above and beyond, and the company responded with "We don't care." So now he's putting in "only" 100%, so he's just an average Joe now. Suddenly company says "Whoa! Wait, we do care! We care in that we want you to put more money in our wallet, we just don't give a **** about you personally and don't want to reward you for your excellent behavior. Please stop being only as good as a normal employee. Keep giving us 200% as we've come to expect, or we'll give you the boot (and hopefully steal your severance money)." … which one is childish?

Comment: I didn't say the company was right.  But if OP is being objective, worker has not only cut back but is making a stink.

Comment: @WGroleau Who wouldn't, after getting a monumental stab in the back like this one? This employee never "cut back"; he was going way above and beyond what he should've done. Your perspective is *objectively* wrong here. Going "down" to 100% from ~200% is not "cutting back"; it's doing what his employer asked of him in the first place. If I were that employee, I wouldn't be happy at all and would certainly make the company pay back the $700K OP said he accrued with OT.

Comment: Little point in arguing opinions

Comment: @Aaron The engineer is also "encouraging other engineers to do the same." His 200% might have dropped to 100%, but he's also pulling everyone else down too. That's an unprofessional thing to do

Comment: @Mars He's making everyone aware that they shouldn't put more than 100% because it will not be rewarded in any kind. That is proffesionalims. That way they will not only give 100% but also make time to check quality of their work.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Do you earn 700K + salary for 200%? Do you make 700K for 1000%? Outside of the US, you likely don't earn 700K for even >>2000% <<.

Comment: The engineer could be fighting for workers rights or something. From what it sounds like, they could do it better. From the little info that we have, none of it sounds like a professional attempt at changing the work place--there were likely many more channels that they could have tried before trying to turn all of the employees against management. It's not just a personal rebellion, they're trying to start a war, like an teenager.

Comment: @Mars See Richard U answer. He don't have to fight for workers right. He feel (rightfully) wronged so he let everyone know why. And they made a proffesional attemp at changing the workplace. The company nswer was "sit down for X time just becuse". AND the company (or someone in there) should be aware yout don't get 700K for 15 hours a week of OT for 2 years. BUT he didn't get the money yet. Engeener expect reward proportional to his effort. He's meet with clling him millenials, expectation of doing those extra thing for free. Who's acting as teenager?

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY How was the engineer wronged? The company has rules, the company didn't bend the rules and now the engineer is upset. The company didn't do anything *wrong.* They may have done something *inadvisable* (failing to meet the demands of a valuable asset), but they have not done anything wrong.

Comment: @Mars Company knowingly benefitem from employee bending the rules and would still like to do it. So now the engeener taken the role of HR informing everyone they should now the rules and stick to them. This is what they did wrong - they acted as bending the rules could have happened in both direction.

Comment: What rules did the employee bend?

Comment: @Mars Did OT. We assume that if you do OT it means you are hired on some sort of 9-5. That's the rule, you work 8 hours a day. You think you need to work more? No, the company need to hire more people to accomodate for their need. Or fire you if you cannot do your work in set time.

Comment: @WGroleau it isn't "childish" to stop working overtime when it becomes clear that it won't benefit you. *Not* putting in overtime is the default, that's why it's called **over**time.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Working OT isn't bending any rules, especially when you can receive extra money for it. In fact, in the US, engineers are considered a special category, so working over 40 hours is NOT legal overtime. The company is offering to pay extra as an *incentive*, that is not required by law.

Comment: @Mars Again - He have not been yet paid. And they don't want to pay him. Per OP statement he's supposed to make him quit so the company can not pay him.

Comment: @WGroleau instead of arguing a point in comments (which aren't supposed to be dialog anyway), why not make an answer elaborating your points, so that we may up (or down) vote them.

Comment: @Mars Even if the company didn't do anything *technically wrong*, the employee hasn't either. Employee was told his extra work wasn't going to be rewarded, so they stuck to the *actual requirements* rather than putting in extra work... while telling others that their extra work won't be rewarded. No-one's *done* anything wrong (YET, this question is dangerously close to asking how the company can get away with doing something wrong - i.e. withholding severance), but the company *has* shut down a potentially mutually-beneficial relationship with its employees (if OT led to more promotions).

Comment: @Delioth I'm not saying the employee has done something wrong and I don't think the company has done something wrong YET (although it seems to have been discussed...). I do think that the engineer could have handled things better and seconded the opinion that some of the engineer's actions have been childish

Comment: @Mars Given the tone of the question,it pictures the engineer as going around screaming it at everyone. But since the O.P. hasn't said anything *at all* or even logged in since the question was asked, makes me think that we won't know if that's the case. Or if it was simply said to others, in a civil manner, that their work is worthless towards a promotion. How the engineer trully acted is a unknown. Saying the engineer handled this in a childish way without any clarification is quite a stretch. Also, they dont want to pay the 700k, so, there's motivation to taint their image.

Answer (score 128):

I don't see an overeager engineer, I see a disgruntled one.

In this answer, I addressed a similar problem, but one that had gotten worse

[How can I deal with troublesome Professional Engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63205/how-can-i-deal-with-troublesome-professional-engineer/63268#63268)

You have taught your formerly eager engineer that effort doesn't matter. He's put in 700K worth of overtime which he has not taken, and you think the problem lies with HIM?

Of course he's putting in the minimum now; you've taught him that his hard work is rewarded only with words. If you discipline him, the very best case scenario is that he will walk, and I don't mean that that is good.

You have an employee who is, or was, so dedicated, that simply slowing his roll down to normal has a profound effect. Push him out the door, and you'll likely have a wrongful termination suit, followed by someone working for a competitor who has a fanatical drive to help them put you out of business.

Your company made a mistake, now it's time to correct it.

If you want to reign him in, find some way to give him a title that reflects his dedication.

"assistant director" or something like that.

He's hungry, don't ruin his appetite.

Comment: "If you discipline him, the very best case scenario is that he will walk, and I don't mean that that is good.  Push him out the door, and you'll likely have a wrongful termination suit, followed by someone working for a competitor who has a fanatical drive to help them put you out of business." - Not only will the company open themselves up to a wrongful termination suit, they will also have to pay $700K severance to an employee, who will then likely transfer to their direct competition.

Comment: *You taught him his effort is rewarded only with words.* ... and at least $700K

Comment: PS, if you want to pay me $700K, I'll work even without words. Or any words you want to give, good or bad :)

Comment: I read the question referenced in this answer when it came up years ago and to this day  from time to time I wonder what happened with that company and employee.

Comment: @Mars _"senior management (on principal) doesn't want to pay $700,000"_. That money doesn't exist. The company has no intention of honoring their agreement to pay it. If the engineer manages to get it, it will be after a massive legal fight, and __not__ as a reward given by the company.

Comment: @Mars that 700k is for uncompensated OT.  He walks, he loses it.

Comment: While true that it is (potentially for) uncompensated OT, it is true that if the engineer walks he won't get it; therefor its also ***very very true*** that he won't walk. He's going to do the absolute bare minimum as dictated by his contract (which he will undoubtedly pay a lawyer a few hundred to review) in an attempt to get the company to fire him. Why? Because $700,000 that's why. The engineer has a financial incentive to sit in his chair and do *nothing* if it means he gets that money.

Comment: In the case of this question and the one @RichardU linked, it seems these technical minded engineers have stronger soft skills than most people seem to credit them with: they sound plenty clever if they can make the company bleed and not be fired for cause.

Comment: I think the 700k is a different issue from the denial of a promotion. His work had the value of 700k, and now this crappy company is trying to cheat him out of it.

Comment: @Mars exactly.  And this guy is going to make sure they pay, one way or another.

Beware of him that is slow to anger; for when it is long coming, it is the stronger when it comes, and the longer kept. Abused patience turns to fury.

Comment: @RichardU This guy reallllly doesn't seem slow to anger. The way it's described, it seems like the first time he didn't get what he wanted, he threw a tantrum is trying to bring the team with him

Comment: @Cloud Software engineers are kinda like artists in our work. It's going to be inconsistent at times, and issues that arise are very very close to intangible (and sometimes avoidable, sometimes unavoidable). Especially since "what software engineers do" can often be equated to "witchcraft" in management's mind, there's a lot of leeway.

Comment: @Mars "Tantrum" isn't really the right word for "returning to just doing your job, and reminding others that hard work has no reward". If a team doing the work they're contracted to do is "bringing down a team", then that's the worst kind of terrible management.

Comment: @Mars Far from a tantrum.  Considering they essentially stole 2 years worth of work from him, I would call his actions remarkably restrained

Comment: @Delioth The employee is actively trying to prevent others from going above and beyond. That's different from just doing that by himself. Also, the engineer is discouraging the study of subjects that would be useful for work. That's not very helpful to other employees in the long run (unless they will be leaving too), not to mention not helpful for the company.

Comment: From my experience, it usually goes 1) Learn new useful skill, 2) Get paid more, not the other way around.

Comment: @RichardU I disagree, solely on the premise that you are basing everything on a wrongdoing that the company has yet to commit. You assume that they *never* intended to pay out, but we have nothing to base that on, and following, the money **does** exist.

Comment: And very importantly, the engineer in question is likely unaware that the company is currently considering shady things, so **the engineer currently still thinks they have the money**

Comment: From the perspective of the engineer, they got told that they lack the years at the company + X,Y,Z other skills and got passed over for the promotion. That's all.

Comment: @Mars He's not trying to prevent others from going above and beyond, he's merely - and *accurately* - advising them that doing so will get them absolutely no rewards as the company does not value dedication or performance.

Comment: @Shadur As far as the person in question is concerned, going above and beyond earned them 700k. That's not "no rewards". The employee seems to be *very* well compensated (assuming the company does not cheat him out of his money). The only thing that goes towards your "no rewards" statement is that the person got passed over for a promotion. I'll take 700k even if it means I'm not getting promoted for another year :)

Comment: @Mars they gave him neither.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter Welcome back. Last I saw, you were taking a break. I don't know if we can say that they gave him neither. I haven't seen where OP stated a conclusion to these events. In that case, I think it's only safe to assume the following: 1) They didn't give him the promotion. 2) The engineer in question is acting poorly WITHOUT knowing that there is a chance of losing his 700k.

Comment: @Shadur More than a year has passed since this post and I (would like to believe that) have grown a bit. Even more so now, I would consider an engineer that goes out of their way to say "don't study this, the company won't reward you for it anyway." is *actively* trying to prevent others from going above and beyond.

Comment: @Mars Cheers mate.  Yeah, I'm back for now.  And, yeah.  The engineer is staging a job action.

Answer (score 57):

The way to get rid of him is very simple: give him *exactly* what he asked for.

Find an "engineering director" position which is 100% management (preferably, the most unpleasant aspects of management that exist in your organization) and appoint him to it.

His much vaunted technical ability will then be of no use to him whatsoever.

And keep his nose firmly on the management grindstone by insisting on detailed weekly status reports when he fails to achieve impossible management objectives.

He won't be *your* problem for much longer.

Comment: Wonderfully openly evil answer to a closeted evil question. +1

Comment: ... and since it's at his own insistence, against corporate guidelines, he'd be hard-pressed to to frame this as constructive dismissal. That's Evil with a capital E.

Comment: Yes!  And from the description, it seems as though this would be a textbook case of the Peter Principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle  So he becomes a manager, is really bad at it, gets fired, and discovers that he can no longer get engineering jobs because of his management experience :-)

Comment: The downside of this answer is that you loose the skills that are so valuable to the company....

Comment: There's a lot of truth to this, but with a grain of salt.  Engineering is not management, but that doesn't mean an excelling engineer will not excel at management.  Being smart is a trait, not a feature of a some job description.

Comment: @RandomUs1r: I would argue that being "smart" is not really required of a manager, and can often be a detriment.  Of course there are people who can be both good engineers and good managers, but from the description in the question, this person does not appear to be one of them.

Comment: @jamesqf Sure, I don't think this person understands that to be promoted high up they'd eventually have to give up coding, but there's a lot of technical aspects around coding that are more important than the code itself (gasp): compliance, governance, & major functionality decisions are a few that come to mind.  Would you want the guy building your house to architect the development of the housing complex it's in? Probably not, same w coders & managers, but the guy designing the housing complex has to be aware of exactly what can or can't be done in house building.

Comment: @jamesqf The point is to have the engineer quit, not get fired. Quitting (presumably) forfeits the right to the "unique" severance package

Comment: Interesting answer that spawned another question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145780/can-you-be-promoted-and-then-fired-for-cause-performance/145781?noredirect=1#comment469973_145781

Comment: alephzero's answer is a Machiavellian tactic used in toxic workplaces. Don't use it. It'll corrupt and demoralize the organization at all levels. I've heard of a person who was offered such a poison-apple promotion. He smelt a rat and resigned. About the OP's employee, a person who turns so negative on not being promoted immediately, is definitely not someone who has the maturity to be promoted.

Comment: Engineer to Director is still quite a jump. As a stepping stone, you can start by promoting him to a management position - put him in charge of the very people he's been telling to work to rule.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I really dislike that the idea that to get high salaries, at some point you have to go to management and the likes...

Comment: @jamesqf `and discovers that he can no longer get engineering jobs because of his management experience` - why is that? Software engineers with management experience find it more difficult to get software engineer jobs at other companies?

Comment: @Abdul Low level management or tech lead? No, that's still a bonus on a resume. Middle to upper management? That's as good as a well-justified employment gap for an engineer. The assumption will be that you've lost working knowledge and haven't kept up with the brass tacks of changes in tech stacks.

Comment: @Abdul: While I don't know for sure (never having been, or wanted to be, in management), it's been my experience that people hiring SWEs a) like to see recent experience as a SWE, and b) like to think that the person they're hiring is going to STAY a SWE for a while, instead of immediately looking for a "promotion" to management.

Comment: This engineer definitely sounds like the kind of entitled, self-important asshole who makes management a poison.  Try not to put too many people under him, or only the ones you were wishing to get rid of. Double the efficiency..

Comment: I see Catbert has joined the discussion.

Comment: I hope that this answer is intended to sarcastically show that the question is based on a false premise that would lead to a horrible outcome.

Comment: That is incredibly wasteful.  You're suggesting they destroy a man's life over a disagreement that could easily be resolved to the benefit of all, and set up the company for a lawsuit on the grounds of constructive termination

Answer (score 57):

It looks like your company has its reasons to not promote someone before they've spent a certain amount of time in a previous role, to minimize risk. The company is also not willing to bend those rules for this employee, because it prefers to risk losing a well-performing employee rather than risk having a potentially ill-prepared person take a management role.

Regardless of whether that is a wise policy or not, it seems to be policy, so you need to be straight with them and tell them that they cannot work around that. You seem to have done that and you have gotten the expected results: if they only need to let time pass, that's what they will do. **This is the consequence of the policy of minimizing risk, and not the fault of the employee**.

You cannot discipline them for doing what is expected of them in the contract. You cannot discipline them for advising their coworkers to do the same. If you expect more, state so in the contract and increase their compensation accordingly. The company can't have its cake and eat it too.

Comment: +1 A bad manager (in this case, one who is not seasoned enough) will ruin things faster than you can ever imagine.

Comment: @RonJohn Agreed. However, OP sounds like the bad manager in this case.

Comment: @Cloud I just love it when people jump to conclusions.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't quite follow. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Cloud you're jumping to the conclusion that he is a **bad** manager, which isn't at all justified.  What I see is a man who's trying to handle an arrogant, prima donna who's more than a bit of a jerk.

Comment: @RonJohn OP hasn't addressed whether or not this engineer's request to go over the individual sub-skills needed to earn the promotion (and areas that the engineer needs to work on). Also, OPs attitude seems bigoted, if not outright ageist. Regardless of which party is "in the right" on this topic, OP sounds like a poor manager.

Comment: @Cloud I've met some **poor** managers, and I've seen bad manager ruin companies.  This guy doesn't give **me** the impression of being a **poor** manager.  But then, I'm old and remember when I was a brash and eager know-it-all who worked long hours.  (I, though, worked for the love of coding, **not** to be a Director at such a young age.)

Comment: @RonJohn FWIW, this engineer does seem emotionally charged, and a potential risk. IMHO, OP seems even worse, and is a definite risk. In the case of the engineer, I can't really fault a young guy for wanting to have a ballistic career trajectory, especially if he can deliver.

Comment: @Cloud no, I don't blame him for being ambitious either.  However, IMO only with time can you learn that the stuff they teach you in tech books is **NOT** what Engineering **Directors** deal with.  (Of course, the old men in charge have been dealing with impatient, ambitious know-it-all kids for a long, long time.)

Comment: @RonJohn Well the OP does sound like a bad manager to me. Specifically the way they take over time as granted and then are surprised to find out - not a surprise to anyone else really - that the engineer is not doing OT any more, and then proceed to ask for ways to discipline this engineer. If this is not a bad manager to you, well...you have my condolences.

Comment: +1 for `This is the consequence of the policy of minimizing risk, and not the fault of the employee.`

Comment: @Billy.Bob the title, I think, is poorly worded, since he also writes, "How do I **straighten out* this **formerly useful** employee?"  They want to **fix him**, not punish him.

Comment: @RonJohn I'm not a native speaker, but the title says that he wants to **disciple** him and this dictionary says "to **punish** someone". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discipline

Comment: @Billy.Bob remember also that "discipline" originally meant "teach" (having the same root as "disciple" and where the positive meaning "discipline" came from).

Comment: @Cyonis perfect timing.  I just made a comment to Billy.Bob about that.

Comment: @Cyonis look also at the secondary meaning of the verb: "to teach someone to behave in a controlled way".

Comment: @RonJohn You could be right about the poorly worded title. Either way, my conclusion does not change: that the OP is a bad manager.

Comment: @Cloud I agree with RonJohn on this one. Aside from dubious morals, there doesn't seem to be anything at all that you can base your measure of OP's management skills with. (The millennial comment, while unnecessary, was still revealing of the company's culture. Clearly they expect that somethings come *with time* (\*cough\* emotional maturity \*cough\*)).

Comment: @Billy.Bob Seeing as the bolded part of the OP is that the engineer is encouraging OTHERS not to do things. If the engineer was just not doing OT, there probably wouldn't be a desire to fire them. **Bringing down others with him is the problem here**, not not doing OT.

Comment: @Mars How do you know the OP is not interpreting something like "oh man let me tell you after cutting my OT, life just feels so much better" as encouraging others not to do OT? If OP's company is not exploiting engineers, messing up their planning or screwing that engineer, would this ever happen? Now I agree the engineer could have handled this more professionally but management is largely at fault here.

Comment: @Billy.Bob *cutting overtime to nothing, focusing on his personal blog/LinkedIn to show off his knowledge, focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) and encouraging other engineers to do the same* Now I'm not a grammar expert, but it seems like there's two ways you can read that sentence. Either he is encouraging others to do all of the above, or he's encouraging others to study things other than work related stuff. Neither of those is just saying life feels better.

Comment: From what it sounds like, life was great for the engineer. Making bank and getting everything they wanted, *until the time that they didn't.* Maybe there is more to it, but we don't have any of that info.

Comment: Fact: This company has a good enough work environment that the engineer worked for 3+ years here and wants to be director of engineering. Fact: The engineer is *probably* unaware the company is trying to screw him over by getting him to quit. Fact: He was denied the promotion for **multiple reasons**, one of which was lack of internal company experience.

Comment: @Mars you are right, we don't know. We don't know if life feels better for the engineer. And who knows? Maybe having more time for all those personal things IS making his life better? Maybe the engineer is preparing for his departure to pursue a better opportunity elsewhere and hence doing those personal things. We don't know. It's just one possibility.

Comment: @Billy.Bob I don't understand what you're saying there. I agree that the engineer seems like they are getting ready to make a departure though (updating LinkedIn). So the engineer got passed over for a promotion *once* and has decided they want to leave. Also reinforces the immature image for me. Seems like a waste of the severance package though :(

Answer (score 46):

A lot of people have already discussed the *employee* in question at length, and I don't feel that retreading that ground would provide you with much value at this point.

Instead, I would like to focus on *everyone else*; more importantly, this line in your question:

> ...I'm receiving recommendations to encourage this millennial to quit.

Two major things stand out to me about this statement:

- The culture of your company is one that implies that there are norms of working overtime and putting in 110% at all waking hours of the day.  Because the employee isn't fitting in with the corporate mold, others are wanting them to either conform or "quit".
- There's a slight tinge of ageism on the sake of mentioning that they're a millennial.  If they found out that this was the reason that they were being convinced to leave the company or dismissed, **you could land yourself in *very* hot legal waters**.

## Your purpose as a leader should be to ***shield*** and ***unblock***.

You have missed a key opportunity to **shield** your employee from the criticisms and stigma that your job has thrust upon him.  If nothing else, I would start with the people who want them to quit, asking what about it makes them not want to work with them anymore.  You should be prepared to defend your employee's work ethic, even if they cut back on overtime - which, if we recall, is 100% ***voluntary***.

You should also look to **unblock** them and prescribe to them exactly what it is they need to advance.  Sitting in a chair for X years isn't really a satisfactory answer, and you should be prepared to go into more detail.  Clearly you have an employee who is looking to commit themselves to live up to the expectations you set, so you should totally set them.

Comment: To add to this great answer, I'd like to point out that with the "encourage him to quit" attitude perhaps the best thing for you to do for everyone involved is help him get a better job somewhere else.  If you do it right and tell him honestly about how incompetent the management there is, maybe you'll be able to go work for him when things start to fall apart.

Comment: "They" might be pushing him to quit because -- as you say -- of "ageism" (in this industry? LOL) or because he's not fitting into the corporate culture.  **OR** it's because he's "focusing on his personal blog/LinkedIn to show off his knowledge, focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) and encouraging other engineers to do the same" which "has caused a lot of disruptions in the company".  OP isn't handling things well, but the engineer in question really seems like a selfish **prima donna** who's threatening to take his ball and go home.

Comment: I would argue that the correct way to shield an employee who's doing significant amounts of overtime is to send them home at a sensible time.  Ultimately, working that much overtime is bad for your health; and if they're really that good of an employee, burning them out would be a bad thing.

Comment: @RonJohn *the engineer in question really seems like a selfish prima donna who's threatening to take his ball and go home*  It's his *only* right here : to work to rule (actually what management told him to do !) and if the so-called "prima donna" isn't happy with his employer they can do *exactly* that.  I bet the prima donnas who manage the company would bail if their bonuses weren't paid.  The engineer is an *employee* not a bloody slave.

Comment: @StephenG "The engineer is an employee not a bloody slave" which is why they're paying him a lot of money, and keep promoting him.

Comment: @RonJohn The whole problem is that this question asks how **not** to promote him while also **not** paying him his OT severance.  The engineer has actually shown they are a much better manager and negotiator than their managers are  by getting a deal that puts them firmly in the driving seat.  This engineer is *already* a good leader and negotiator and should be fast tracked, not held up by crooks.  They'll be fast tracked somewhere else, that's for sure.  Fire the managers who want rid of this guy, keep the engineer.

Comment: @RonJohn, actually I don't see the engineer as a prima donna. "A very temperamental person with an inflated view of their own talent or importance." https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/prima_donna It seems like they have a very good idea of their own talent, which seems extensive to learn and excel at new tech in a week. The only problem is "importance", which the OP sets as very low when an excellent engineer should have high importance instead. This goes back to the OP being a bad manager and seemingly being afraid of losing their own job to this "bad employee".

Comment: @computercarguy The engineer feels important enough that they should have an out-of-season promotion and be made an exception to the 3 year rule, despite being denied the promotion for multiple reasons. That sounds inflated to me. I personally find the response of the engineer (not cutting OT--that sounds normal and more like loss of motivation than purposeful) to be "temperamental." I guess that makes this engineer a textbook prima donna!

Comment: @makoto I think technically overtime is not 100% voluntary for an engineer in the US, because engineers are "professionals," a special legal category. I gotta look it up the details though

Comment: @Mars:  I as an engineer in the States am salaried, meaning that I don't get paid for overtime, and if there _is_ overtime, there's some expectation that I work it without extra pay.  However, in the context of the OP, since they explicitly call out overtime and overtime benefits, this tells me that they are hourly, and thus, OT would be entirely optional since the benefit is time-and-a-half.

Comment: @Mars, as a software engineer myself, OT should never be a requirement. I've worked salaried at a couple places, and IF there's a time I need to work beyond normal working hours, it's usually at the expense of the hours the next day. If it's a Saturday, it's only 1 a year. More than that and I walk, since the USA has BS rules about salaried IT being exempt from OT pay, but that doesn't mean it's required or should be abused. Do you work for your employer for free? I try very hard not to. Call me a prima donna if you want and I'll call you gullible.

Comment: @computercarguy In practice, they usually get OT pay. But the concept is that they are required to finish the task they agreed to, by the time they agreed to. This also gives you the freedom to work OT and receive a higher pay, as I did

Comment: @Makoto I'm salaried and get OT pay. You can't assume everyone has the same contract as you

Comment: @Mars: So you as an engineer are salaried and do get OT benefits.  Interesting, since that's not what "salaried" implies.

Comment: @Makoto I think that may just be your own image of the word? For example, government postal workers are salaried and may receive overtime.

Comment: Of course, OT is much more grey for a salaried employee. If you're not hourly, then what is your "time and a half"? It then falls down to contract. In my case, I actually have a buffer for the number of hours of OT I have to work before receiving OT.

Comment: @Mars, my first software dev job was for a company that essentially grew to understand "salary" as "slave". They practiced Agile for a while, but it wasn't getting the results the sales "needed", so they went to "do what I tell you or else". "You don't have to do OT, if you work fast and hard enough, but we need you to do this when by the time we tell you." And no, that didn't pay any OT, not even at a regular hourly rate. https://www.dol.gov/whd/overtime/fs17e_computer.htm

Comment: @computercarguy That's unfortunate. One example, or even 100 examples does NOT make it a rule or significant though.It just reinforces my statement that it falls down to contract. I believe that a significant amount of those dirty companies exist. I also believe a significant amount of proper companies exist. I don't have any data regarding the ratios.

Comment: @Mars, it may not make it a rule, but it shows my own experience is different than yours and so it can't be discounted as hearsay. Ratios don't matter when talking about a specific instance. From what the OP says, there's a significant probability they have a toxic workplace, regardless of statistics. Even if it's a 1% chance that company is like the one I worked for, from the sounds of it, it's highly probable it's within that 1%.

Answer (score 25):

It's interesting that you claim "overeager" because it implies that this person does not currently have the skillset to be successful in their desired role. My answer is based on accepting this implication at face value.

---

Question for you:

Do you want this person to become an engineering director?

---

If **yes**:

Excellent, you have a driven and highly motivated individual within your company who sounds like they want the company to succeed.

Get something in place for building this person up to become an excellent director. You wouldn't want someone who is severely technical and lacking in human skills to start directing humans, would you? Make sure that this training focuses on soft skills. Within the next year they should be ready to become a director.

FYI, their thirst won't stop. Get ready for their next promotion.

---

If **no**:

Your company is going to lose this person unless a significant pay/benfits bump will sate their thirst.

Comment: How much leadership is this person doing now? How big of a jump is it to engineering director? If it's a pretty big jump in responsibility then it may take longer than a year (e.g. if their senior title is senior in name only and they're not actually overseeing anyone or anything right now, then it could take another 5-10 years).

Comment: @bob maybe my example is overly simplistic but I would assume that an honest evaluation happens after one year to let the person know whether or not they've developed their soft skills enough.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.

Comment: @bob At least that's how things play out in a perfect world. Based on OP's post this engineer might be too far gone to even listen and accept an honest evaluation. The engineer might be ruthlessly thinking that once they complete a punch-list then they can get the promotion. It's possible that a punch-list can be created for soft skills but then you run the risk of the person not properly internalizing the experience.

Comment: I like this. Also, the OP mentions having interviews regarding all of the engineer's inadequacies and progress, suggesting that the engineer does not, in fact, have the skillset that those in charge of hiring believe is needed.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of working him out of the company, put him on a "fast track" or "talent programme" or some such. Give him a schedule of things that he must achieve - some of those will be raw qualifications (eg. sit the company's "new managers" training course), and others will be experiences like "come up with a training presentation and invite people to come" (to see how well he trains, and how many people come). Get him to mentor a junior team member, with the stated aim of having the junior person reach some level of attainment. Maybe see if someone senior outside of his normal world will mentor him (an hour or two once a quarter - so not a huge time investment for them!).

I guess the point here is to try develop this individual to the point that he could take on the new role. Along the way, evaluate his performance. Taking the presentation point, if his first presentation is boring and only has 8 people in it, then hopefully he'll take the initiative, solicit feedback and improve for the next one he does without you specifically asking him to do it. Likewise, with the mentoring, it's an opportunity for him to show how he'd deal with junior team members, perhaps people who he doesn't naturally get on with that well, etc etc.

I strongly suspect that he'll fail at a lot of these tasks because they're nothing like engineering. Failure isn't an excuse to fire him, but it is an opportunity for you to explain in clear terms how his performance isn't yet up to the new role (and what he needs to do to solve those problems). You may find that if he reflects honestly, that he'd prefer to be a senior engineer than a junior manager, or maybe he'll surprise you and be the best manager you ever saw. Either way, it'll be a positive experience for you and him, and will likely earn you and the company a great deal of respect for investing in people and managing skilfully.

Comment: Yes, train this engineer to be the manager he wants to be. Failing at specific tasks is only bad if you don't learn something from it. And yes, with this guy's track record of learning new material, he could definitely be a great manager, one that continues to help "over eager" engineers like himself, rather than just beating them into the same mold time and again, like the OP.

Comment: "I strongly suspect that he'll fail at a lot of these tasks because they're nothing like engineering." Nice. I like it.

Answer (score 14):

**Note: this answer assumes the employee only has 4 years of experience (based on the question wording) without much leadership experience yet.**

## Experience and technical chops / productivity aren't the same thing

The employee in question sounds a lot like me when I first started out, though I wasn't as much of a technical superstar, nor did I resort to insubordination when my fast-track promotion hopes were dashed. What I learned, and what most junior engineers learn the hard way as they gain experience and become senior engineers is that technical prowess and productivity cannot substitute for experience.  It made no sense to me. I thought I was smart, was good at what I did, and had ambition and initiative; wasn't that enough? What I didn't learn for quite a few years was that experience provides you with many important soft skills that are pretty much impossible for most of us to acquire any other way:

- **Understanding of risk management:** how to properly assess risk, when to take risks, and when to avoid risks;
- **How to deal with others:** dealing with your peers, subordinates, and superiors;
- **How to manage a schedule**: delivering on time, even if it means cutting corners (within company policies on quality; i.e. the iron triangle);
- **Understanding your company's organizational structure**;
- **Understanding your company's own unique internal politics and policies**;
- **Balancing theoretical correctness with project requirements:** sometimes the "correct" design pattern isn't best for a project;
- **In general how to avoid common mistakes**

Not only are these skills difficult if not impossible to acquire without experience and not at all the same as technical prowess or productivity, but hiring managers have to consider risk when making hiring and promotion decisions. It's risky to assume that someone without experience is ready for leadership. Based on the behavior described in the question, it seems like the employee in question has not mastered these soft skills--in any case they don't know how to deal with their superiors in a constructive way or how to demonstrate that they already have the soft skills necessary to lead (e.g. they could show how leadership activities on their own time demonstrate the skills needed for a leadership role in the workplace).

## Leaders must have experience

Leaders must have a wide variety of soft skills beyond technical chops and productivity, and unless the candidate in question is a social savant, experience is how these skills are acquired. This is why minimum experience requirements are used, and why it's not a good idea to put a junior engineer in a leadership role or to promote too soon.

In addition, leaders need experience leading at the level of responsibility that their role requires. So 10 years of engineering experience as an individual contributor doesn't qualify someone to become CEO. It does however likely qualify them to become a team lead, and after a few years of success as a team lead, they could climb a level, and after a few years climb another, and *eventually* possibly reach the CEO level if they demonstrate success in leading increasingly large teams and impactful projects. There are always exceptions, but exceptions are inherently risky. This is why experience is so valuable and so important.

## Deal with the insubordination immediately

It's understandable that your subordinate is upset, but you do need to deal with the insubordination right away. It's okay for the person in question to stop doing unpaid overtime (it's better actually; why let them burn themselves out?), but it is not at all okay for them to be undercutting you to the rest of your company. Why do I say this? Based on this section from the question, specifically the part that I've marked in bold:

> We've had a serious problem with him this month: since a formal meeting where he's noted he's not happy being magically promoted on a whim, he's made a point of cutting overtime to nothing, focusing on his personal blog/LinkedIn to show off his knowledge, focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) **and encouraging other engineers to do the same. This has caused a lot of disruptions in the company, and I'm receiving recommendations to encourage this millennial to quit.** How do I straighten out this formerly useful employee? He has accrued 2 years of severance in lieu of overtime (due to unique circumstances), and senior management (on principal) doesn't want to pay $700,000 to "fire" someone.

It looks like the employee has done more than simply become disillusioned and stop volunteering their time, which would be totally understandable and 100% okay.  The problem, and where it looks like it became insubordination, is when the employee started "encouraging other engineers to do the same" in a way that "has caused a lot of disruptions in the company" (a company of 5,000+ employees). While we don't have all the info, it sounds this this employee is making **big** waves in the company, which goes way beyond simply being disgruntled and likely crosses the line into insubordination. Honest, natural water-cooler conversations about problems in the company are normal and okay. Going around the company "spreading the word" to encourage disloyalty to the company is not okay (e.g. "the company doesn't care about you!" (probably true, but not good to go around saying); "polish up your resume like I'm doing--this place is a career-killer!"; etc.).

If this assessment is correct, it has to stop now or else the engineer in question needs to be let go. I would recommend a gradual escalation: start with a one-on-one with the engineer, and escalate from there only if needed. Talk to your higher-ups to find out the best process for your company to make sure you protect your company legally and follow all applicable laws. But bottom line, don't tolerate insubordination. It undermines your authority and can destroy your company.

Some people aren't comfortable with my use of the word "insubordination" here, and maybe they're right--I may be stretching the word to fit a non-standard definition. But regardless there seems to be a real problem related to loyalty and submission to authority. I'm seeing this not as overt insubordination--overtly disobeying an order, but rather as covert insubordination--obeying orders to the letter while working against their spirit by working actively against company interests. The latter is actually much more dangerous than the former, so in my view is a very dangerous form of insubordination.

NOTE: Of course if the company is in the wrong here and has built its business model around predatory treatment of employees by requiring frequent unpaid overtime, and the employee is doing everything right, but the example of one employee bucking the trend of killing themselves for the company is causing a ripple effect that's hurting the company's bottom line, then it's clear that this is not a case of insubordination, and the *company* should be dealt with, not the employee. Likewise if the company has crossed serious legal lines, the employee may be acting as a whistleblower of sorts, and could be in the clear ethically and morally. But based simply on the info in the question, none of these *sound* like they're the case.

## Help the employee grow leadership skills

Assuming you resolve the insubordination without having to terminate the employee*, help them grow in their soft skills. Provide training in people skills and project management. Carefully explain to them the importance of soft skills in management. Monitor their progress, and when and only when they are ready, consider them for a promotion to leadership, but start small: don't launch them straight to director. Put them in charge of a small team over a low risk project or task first. See how they do. See whether they like it. See how others like working for them. This also gives them a chance to learn and make mistakes without those mistakes becoming career-limiting, and also keeps them from getting stuck in a high position if they're not suited for it but don't mess up enough to get fired or demoted. If they do well, consider moving them higher. If not then move them back down (if you can).

*NOTE: Only take these steps if you feel your employee was acting out of ignorance and has fully learned their lesson and repented, and thus can be trusted. If not, they probably shouldn't stay with the company, let alone be trained for management. The higher someone is in the company, the more power they have for harm. Don't give that power to someone who has undermined the company in the past and who you feel you can't trust not to do it in the future.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99475/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-how-to-discipline-overeager-engineer).

Answer (score 8):

I happen to think your three-year waiting period accomplished its purpose in this case. You need someone whose work ethic is sustainable, not someone who deflates at short-term setbacks. You wouldn't have discovered that about this person without the waiting period, until it was too late.

If this person had reacted differently by continuing on unabated, I would have gone to great lengths to bend the rules for him to get promoted earlier.

As far as disciplining, for someone this ambitious, failure to be promoted is discipline enough. He seems to be meeting his obligations despite some burn out. He might just need some time in order to find a sustainable leadership style, at which time you can reevaluate.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments, perhaps I perceived the situation inaccurately, or explained myself poorly. It seems to me he was being rewarded for his effort by being put on track for a director position in a year. That is by no means an automatic or insignificant promotion. He also specifically cited his "drive" as a reason to be given special treatment, then seemingly lost his drive when asked for a little patience.

I don't think his actions necessarily disqualify him from a directorship in the normal timeline. His actions just disqualify him from the special treatment of an early promotion, so the company can see how the dust settles first.

Comment: Wait, what?  He puts in literally *thousands* of unpaid overtime hours on a personal drive to succeed, to acclaim from his manager... only to find out that 'We're not going to promote you no matter how good you perform.' - not because of any weaknesses of specific areas the employee can address, but simply because of tenure.  And when that understandably kills the employees motivation to put in *thousands of unpaid overtime hours*, your reaction is, "Haha, I knew your drive wasn't sustainable!"

Comment: I understand this as I've been there (to a lesser degree) and it had a similar effect on me (though I didn't resort to insubordination). But I did my job and learned and grew, and now with 10 years under my belt I have already started leading small teams and am becoming ready to lead even more. So it turns out all that ambition and initiative that I had when I started out was misdirected. The same thing is happening here. And I'm guessing in a few years it will become clear whether the employee in question really is leadership material. But I agree with Karl, nothing has been lost here.

Comment: That said there is some damage control that's needed, first and foremost in resolving the insubordination issue. And beyond that making sure the employee understands *why* tenure matters, and helping them to be deliberate about acquiring the necessary soft skills (see my answer).

Comment: @bob No insubordination happened in this case. Working contract hours, doing and only doing contract work, and explaining to others, that the extra work they put in is **actually worthless** according to company policy is nothing but being a simple employee. It however is not insubordination.

Comment: This is where I'm getting insubordination from: " focusing on generic skills/abilities (at the expense of company-specific skills/technologies) and encouraging other engineers to do the same. This has caused a lot of disruptions in the company, and I'm receiving recommendations to encourage this millennial to quit"

Comment: He seems to have become a troublemaker.

Comment: Agreed. I've read the other answers and cannot believe that people think this guy is director material!

Comment: @bob It seems like OP is leaving out some important details. This engineer sounds incredibly smart. Maybe other engineers simple emulate him and also realized that loyalty and initiative aren't rewarded. If someone was going around literally telling people to cut into the company's bottom line, it would likely be ample reason to release this engineer **with cause** and get out of paying severance.

Comment: @bob it's not clearly specified in the OP, but I think they meant this employee is encouraging others to spend their *offtime* learning generic skills instead of specific ones for this position. I'm basing this on that the employee was described as spending their weekends learning. That's not insubordination. If it were to spend their *work time* doing it then I would agree. But, again, it's not really clearly specified.

Comment: "If this person had reacted differently by continuing on unabated", who in their right minds would continue to put in massive overtime for a company when they aren't getting rewarded for it? The fact that the engineer has continued to work on their blog/LinkedIn/etc shows they are continuing unabated, just not for the company that has shown no respect to their employees.

Comment: It's just as good for the company for people to develop generic skills.  Being too caught up in specific skills is not in the best interest of the company.

Comment: @John3136 I agree wholeheartedly with this answer. It seems that people think that working and learning extra hard, above and beyond the job, **entitles** you to get a promotion. This seems naive to me. Do your job well, and ask how and when you can get promoted; then do what you need to do for that. But don't just go full steam on a whim of your own and then get all flabbergasted when the company says you need more actual experience first.

Comment: @John316 It's not particularly surprising given this site is frequented far more heavily by engineers than directors!

Answer (score 6):

I hesitate to add my own answer here, not only because of the good existing answers, but also because of how very divided people seem to be on this topic. But here I go anyway.

## Discipline

Don't do any more than you already have. By not promoting this engineer, you've already basically bit the hand that's been feeding you hours, loyalty, trust, knowledge, and so much more. Remember that saying "once bitten, twice shy"? That's where he's at right now.

As someone in comments tried to say, the well is poisoned, but not by him. He has found out that company policy has offered poisoned water and is informing his compatriots. He does that out of loyalty to them, because he doesn't want them to go through the same thing he has.

## Next Step

It may already be too late, but you need to quit watching his blog, LinkedIn profile, etc. and judging him about it. This is something most people do outside of work normally, but since he's been spending a significant amount of that time on work instead, he's just now doing normal things. Yes, he's probably doing this because he's ready to jump ship, which should be expected from what you've told us. Even if he doesn't quit, you're trying trying to force him out anyway, so why does it matter what he does outside of work?

## Make changes

Businesses used to work on the rule of principle, rather than the rule of law. At some point, though, rules were made to cover where people were confused about a principle or because someone took advantage. Sometime after that, principle got overridden by rules altogether so that no one can do anything without permission, which is a shame in many situations. At various jobs and organizations, I've been "rules lawyer" overridden by people too afraid to do everything to get anything done, even when it's in the best interest of everyone.

The changes you need to make in your organization may not be simple or easy. Maybe you aren't even the one to accomplish the task, but they will help your business by helping your employees feel more satisfaction at work. They'll feel more like what they do matters, instead of it just being a paycheck.

> One study found that happy employees are up to 20% more productive than unhappy employees. When it comes to salespeople, happiness has an even greater impact, raising sales by 37%. But the benefits don't end there.

https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbescoachescouncil/2017/12/13/promoting-employee-happiness-benefits-everyone/#4598bc82581a

Bring back principles as the overriding factor in decisions. One principle is to keep good workers and intelligent people in your business, so when a promotion is keeping them from being their best, do the right thing and promote them. Does it matter if they are missing some minor requirements or they just barely aren't hitting those same requirements? Yes, but that will be fixed in a shorter time frame than figuring out a way to fire them, finding someone else to replace them, and then training the replacement to the now fired employees current level, if that's even possible with the replacement.

## Stress

Since this engineer has been putting in massive overtime and hasn't been burnt out yet, I'd say that he hasn't seen a significant amount of stress, because they enjoy the work and tries to work well because of "the principle of the matter". Now that the rules have come down on him, he's stressed and is likely to get burnt out really quickly.

> "Working under rules is a source of stress. Working under principles is natural, and requires no effort."

https://facilethings.com/blog/en/principles-vs-rules

## Principles over Rules (aka: Rules are meant to be broken)

When you put principles back over rules, you allow your company to do more than just fill seats, provide a paycheck, and do whatever it is your company actually does. It provides a place where humans can be human, which is not fitting into someone else's box. Parents can come in late when the bus breaks down, people can come in and leave early to get to a doctors appointment, people can realize their time is actually appreciated, and, generally, people can quit trying to be robots/drones/zombies trying to make it to the weekend.

You may also notice that the "brown nosers" disappear after a while. When doing the minimum by following the rules doesn't get you an automatic promotion, along with just schmoozing the right people, but rather the hard work and intelligence put into the job gets the promotion, the office becomes more productive with fewer people trying to just "hob nob" their way around.

> - Stay optimistic: Rules are often phrased in pessimistic ways that make it seem like employees don't know how to behave professionally or as adults. Promoting principles in your office will motivate your team to work at their highest ability because they feel like you trust them and they have space to grow and learn.
> - Stay flexible: Always enforcing rules, without any compassion or understanding, can give off the vibe that your employees well-being is the least of your concern. As we preach from a regulatory standpoint, one size does not fit all. It's ok to offer an accommodation in certain circumstances, and you don't have to feel guilty about not giving it to everyone on your team.
> - Stay grounded: Office culture is a tremendous influence on employees' fulfillment. Having managers that respect their employees – and don't let power go to their head – is critical to retaining good talent. And creating an environment where good talent feels autonomous will keep your organization on the road to success.

https://www.nafcu.org/berger-leadership-blog/principles-over-rules

Answer (score 5):

I have read through the answers and comments.  I don't see any mention of this engineers ability to deliver work as required nor any mention of an ability to mentor others in his group and pass on his knowledge.

Unless I am missing something, this person could be brilliant in becoming conversant with yet another new, novel technology. Yet in most cases what is required is completing work on the current code base, in accordance with the established conventions and processes.

Doing lots of overtime is not necessarily an indication of producing commensurate value for the company.  I suspect that at the upper levels of management this person is seen as arrogant and self-entitled, not as being brilliant and an asset.

As the direct manager of this person, I think the critical factor is to be the mentor who shows this "over-eager" engineer how to attain the ambitions by coming into alignment with the organisation's values and expectations.  If the person is impatient and chooses to leave, then that confirms that there is no mutually acceptable common ground.

Comment: His ability to mentor may be implicit when OP says _encouraging other engineers to do the same. **This has caused a lot of disruptions in the company**_ (emphasis mine), if he isn't a good mentor no one would care and no disruption should have been created to the company

Comment: "I suspect that at the upper levels of management this person is seen as arrogant and self-entitled, not as being brilliant and an asset." then they are likely hypocritical, non-technical, and fear for their jobs. If this engineer quits doing OT and it causes lots of disruption, then they were "producing commensurate value for the company", as well as when they learned new tech over the weekends.

Comment: Overtime is not a measure of productivity.  In the long term, it leads inevitably to burnout.  It's unfortunate that this engineer has been led to believe that his overtime was accelerating his promotion

Comment: @FelipePereira To the contrary, however: if he were a good mentor, he would not be mentoring others in a way that causes disruptions.

Comment: @Andrew if his goal was to cause disruptions (because of the denied promotion) and he lead other people to follow him I'd say he has some leadership skills already (even if they are used for evil or good purposes)

Answer (score 4):

I see this differently. You told him the qualifications to get him to the level he wants. He's found that unacceptable and as such stopped doing his work. What will happen when he gets promoted to what he wants now, but late wants something else? Are you willing to put the company in his hands and when things don't work his way, he decides to not do it? You have a company, you told him the qualifications to get where he wants, and rather than work towards that, he wants you to bend the rules just for him.

My advice: let him go now. Yes you get a unique severance pay, but spending $700k now is better than more he would get by staying there in the years you need him. I rather have 2 so-so engineers who can get the same work done but takes longer, than I would having 1 good engineer but could hold my product at risk unless I give him more than what he agreed to accept.

Comment: "He's […] stopped doing his work." I don't recall OP saying the employee stopped doing their work. Just the opposite in fact, that the employee used to do way more than their fair share of the work, and now they are "merely" doing their own fair share. The employee is still doing all their work, according to the question.

Comment: "I rather have 2 so-so engineers who can get the same work done but takes longer, than I would having 1 good engineer..." That logic does not seem to support your conclusion to fire him. Instead, if that is your reasoning, maybe you could suggest that they hire a second person to work on the same tasks he is... then you have your 2 engineers you want.

Comment: I'd rather have two average engineers who don't break production, than one hot-dog superstar who thinks he knows better than everyone else.  (I become the #1 DBA when the previous #1 DBA crashed a **BIG** database in the middle of the day when everyone else told him not to, because of an obscure but published risk.  He knew better, though...  and they walked him out the door that day.)

Comment: +1 to RonJohn. Risk is really important. So are team players. And people aren't computers, and most developers don't start out with the skills they need to successfully get people to do what they want them to do; computers, yes; people, no.

Comment: The only thing I would question is whether you have to jump to firing him. Is there another step you can take like talking to him? But yes if you need to then fire him.

Comment: @bob The way I see it it's only a matter of time before this person holds something of yours hostage in a blackmail scheme to comply with his demand to get promoted. The problem isn't that he's following the overtime rule, but rather he is doing it in spite as he's telling others not to do it. And this behavior only started after his review. Before he was doing overtime eager to do work but only with the assumption he's going to get promoted. Now that failed, he has no reason to do overtime but instead of quitting he's sitting around in spite.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. I'd certainly watch my back with this person.

Comment: When "qualifications" are arbitrary, are they really worth following? There may have been reasoning behind the rule to begin with, but there are always ways to break rules for the right reason. It looks like they did it before and it got them great results. Now they refuse to for age related issues, so it should be expected for an employee to feel a lack of respect they should have earned and act accordingly. I've walked from job for that very same reason.

Comment: You can consider any rule at work as arbitrary as they can be broken and on top of that no two places work the same. With that said, it's not a question of rules being arbitrary, only that when the person in OP found out the were arbitrary they acted badly because they followed the rules only with the assumption that there was an end goal that could not be met.

Comment: @computercarguy More importantly, it seems the guy went full steam without first *finding out* **what** these "arbitrary" qualifications are. That's on him.

Comment: @Andrew, since he was promoted once and the 3 year rule was bent to do it, it follows he would know about it, as the manager would likely have said something about it then. Presumably, the engineer considered the same thing would happen when continuing to work with the same fever pitch as previous to the promotion. The fact that he got blocked by the same rule they bent before, and they bent other rules in the meantime, says the company isn't reliable for it's enforcement of rules and arbitrarily bend or enforce rules for no apparent reason, but their own, sole gains. This is not on him.

Comment: @computercarguy Uhh no. He **assumed** the same thing would happen. This is also faulty logic because 1. it's an even higher up position and therefore has more risk and consequence with it, 2. OP said he "received a promotion from intermediate engineer to senior engineer in his first year (mostly due to his hiring manager messing up and hiring him 'too low')", so that's a unique situation, and 3. if he was already promoted early why expect to be soon after promoted early again? This is unrealistic and likely impractical as well. He probably should therefore not be promoted, in any case.

Comment: @Andrew, if he has 4 yrs in now and was promoted in the first year then he should already have 3 yrs in the seat regardless, not to mention working an extra 1/3rd of a year in OT. And him being hired "too low" means he should have been in that senior position to start with, not that he wasn't fit for it then or now. Also, this engineer has been learning new things at an incredible rate and _on his own time_, so that should also be considered a unique situation and worth promoting. I know it's common to expect some of that, but not at this engineers capability.

Comment: @computercarguy Maybe, that's unclear. That OP mentioned it suggests that maybe he has a few more months to go. Again though: assumption. Entitlement. "If I do this, I will absolutely get this position. I deserve it. It must happen." This is not the proper way to go about getting a promotion. His overtime is entirely (100%) irrelevant, and only exemplifies my point. It's not about, "How much harder have you worked than necessary?" it's, "Are you knowing and abiding by the rules of promotion?"

Comment: @Andrew, when you are applying for a new job, do you state exactly how many years experience you have, as in 2.75 yrs? No, as most people would simply state 3 yrs. Realistically, a few months one way or the other doesn't matter. The OT absolutely counts as it shows initiative, except when it's expected, as presumably it is in this company. If you can't get ahead faster by working harder, then that promotes "the average" over "being exceptional", and a business will suffer due to average (at best) managers, while the exceptional people will go somewhere else, as this company apparently wants.

Comment: @computercarguy Maybe to an ignoramus like the employee in question; but, when he leaves and then people ask why he wasn't promoted, and the managers say, "He didn't work in his current position for 3 years, according to company policy, and he just assumed that he was going to get promoted and got mad when he didn't and left," then they will not think that working harder is discounted. Your problem is in assuming that this guy is exceptional, when more likely I am saying he is probably not so much.

Comment: A person who does not pay attention to rules, nor even try to find them out in the first place, is not going to be a good engineer. He should have done his research. If people don't like the policy that's fine, that would be a legitimate reason to get upset and leave if they don't change it; but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99364/discussion-between-computercarguy-and-andrew).

Comment: "as such stopped doing his work" seems like a gross exaggeration. As stated in the question, he is still doing his job, just not as "overeager" as before.

Answer (score -1):

If you want him to leave on his own accord (to avoid the 700k severance), introduce him to self-employed software engineers – with their mentoring he will see he there is a whole new world out there which is better suited to his skills and risk appetite

Comment: How would encouraging this engineer to become self-employed help? It sounds like he's either waiting to be let go without cause to claim the $700k as severance, or find a better opportunity if one comes along. He also sounds smart enough to be able to do independent development on the side.

Comment: Your advice is to introduce the engineer to "the competition" and expect him to take his skills away from the company? Him reducing his hours has "caused a lot of disruptions in the company", so reducing them to zero isn't? It's likely the engineer is going to ditch this company anyway, so why not help him out the door to avoid paying severance? This is really bad advice all around. It's likely the engineer is has already looked into self-employment and other contract work. The company shouldn't compound their mistakes by actively avoiding the severance.

Comment: nah, they want him to leave, and the self employed make more. win win.